# How to prevent recreation of page in a loader?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am developing a Qt app on Win/Android. My question is very simple.

When my app starts, first a login page welcomes you.
If you want to configure server settings, `ServerInfo.qml` is opened in a loader. The login page and ServerInfo are loaded in the same loader.
My problem is that when I close `ServerInfo.qml`, then load `loginpage.qml` to loader, the loader creates a new instance of `loginpage.qml`. I don't want the page to be created again.

Here is my Qml code :

```
ApplicationWindow  {
  id:mainwindow
  visible: true
  width: 600
  height: 800
  x: Screen.width / 2 - width / 2
  y: Screen.height / 2 - height / 2
  menuBar:MenuBar{
    Menu {
      title:"Edit"
      MenuItem  {
        text:"Sunucu Ayarları"
        onTriggered: {
          loader.source="ServerConfig.qml"
          loader.anchors.centerIn=main
        }
      }
      MenuItem  {
        text:"Çıkış"
        onTriggered: {
          Qt.quit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
Connections  {
  ignoreUnknownSignals: true
  target: process
  onProcessstart: {
    busyrec.visible=true;
    busyloader.item.busytext=text;
    busyloader.item.busyrunnig=true;
  }
  onProcessstop: {
    busyloader.item.busytext=text;
    busyloader.item.busyrunnig=false;
    busyloader.item.busytextcolor="blue"
  }
  Component.onCompleted: {
  // process.onSuccesLogin();
  //TaskResultm.taskresult.Malzemeler.push
       console.log(TaskResultm.taskresult.serilaze());
  }
}

Column  {
  anchors.fill: parent
  Rectangle  {
    id:busyrec
    width: parent.width
    height: (parent.height/10)
    visible:true
    color:"green"
    Loader {
      id:busyloader
      source:"BusyIndicator.qml"
      anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Connections {
      ignoreUnknownSignals: true
    }
  }  

  Rectangle {
    id: main
  //  anchors.fill: parent
    width: parent.width
    height: (parent.height/10)*9
    Loader  {
        id:loader
       source: "LoginPage.qml"
       anchors.centerIn:parent
       focus:true
       property bool valid: item !== null
    }

    Connections {
        ignoreUnknownSignals: true
        target: loader.valid? loader.item : null

        onDirecttomainpage:{
       //     process.getWorkOrderList();
            busyloader.item.switenabled=true;
            busyloader.item.switopacity=1;
            loader.anchors.fill=main;
            loader.source="TaskNavigationMainScreen.qml";

        }
        onServerinfopageclose: {


            loader.source="LoginPage.qml";
              loader.anchors.centerIn=main;

        }
    }


  }

}

    onClosing: {

        if(Qt.platform.os=="android") {

            if(loader.item!==null)
            {
            if(loader.item.objectName==="tasknavigationmain")
                 if(loader.item.zemin===0)
                  close.accepted=true;
                 else
                     close.accepted=false;
            }
        }
        else if (Qt.platform.os=="windows")
        {
             Qt.quit();
                //if(loader.item!==null)
              //  if(loader.item.objectName==="tasknavigationmain")
             //       console.log(loader.item.stackViewItem.depth);
        }


    }


  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) instead of a `Loader`, it will keep previous "forms" alive as you push new ones on top, and you can always go back and forth.

A loader will load a single element, if you load another, the old one will be destroyed, there is no way around that.

Comment: You can have multiple loaders, though. The idiom is: one loader per item you wish to load later.

Comment: You can have as many as you want, but you will still have to implement some sort of visibility and order management. It kind of defeats the purpose, especially when you already have the right solution to the problem out of the box.